# Enumerate days between two dates - Flex AS3

Tags: apache-flex, date, range, enumerate

Does Flex dateChooser have any capabilities to enumerate dates for a given range?
Say Start date is 2013-12-25 and end date is 2014-03-15. How can I print:

```
2013-12-25
2013-12-26
2013-12-27
...
2013-12-31
2014-01-01
2014-01-02
...
2014-03-15
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't, but this is something you could do by creating your own function easily:

```
protected function getDatesBetween(start:Date,end:Date):Array{
  var dates:Array = [start];
  const DAY_TO_MS:Number = 24*60*60*1000;

  var next:Date = new Date( start.getTime() + DAY_TO_MS );
  while( next.getTime() < end.getTime() ){
    dates.push( next );
    next = new Date( next.getTime() + DAY_TO_MS );
  }     
  dates.push( end );

  return dates;
}
```